# Не отображаются изображение в окне PyQt5, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qrc

Хочу реализовать картинку в своем приложении, но при открытии приложения, консоль выдаёт:

> Could not create pixmap from :\1\1.png
> Could not create pixmap from :\1\1.png
> Could not create pixmap from :\1\1.png

Причем есть похожий файл, где все работает на ура. 
Не могу понять, почему возникает ошибка?

`TaskWindow301` - окно где должна быть картинка ( я вставляю картинку в `Qlabel`)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(534, 498)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 220, 231, 31))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 260, 61, 31))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.AnswerEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 270, 141, 20))
        self.AnswerEdit.setObjectName("AnswerEdit")
        self.SetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 310, 101, 31))
        self.SetButton.setObjectName("SetButton")
        self.CheckButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 310, 111, 31))
        self.CheckButton.setObjectName("CheckButton")
        self.AnswerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 270, 101, 21))
        self.AnswerLabel.setText("")
        self.AnswerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.AnswerLabel.setObjectName("AnswerLabel")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 380, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 380, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 261, 161))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/1/1.png);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/1/1.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 534, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "What do you see on this photo?"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type here:"))
        self.SetButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Answer"))
        self.CheckButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Answer"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to previous test"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to contests"))
    import kik_rc
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

файл **`kik_rc.py`** приложить не могу, ибо там очень много строк кода. 
Вот самое начало и конец этого файла:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
qt_resource_data = b"\
qt_version = [int(v) for v in QtCore.qVersion().split('.')]
if qt_version < [5, 8, 0]:
    rcc_version = 1
    qt_resource_struct = qt_resource_struct_v1
else:
    rcc_version = 2
    qt_resource_struct = qt_resource_struct_v2

def qInitResources():
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(rcc_version, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

def qCleanupResources():
    QtCore.qUnregisterResourceData(rcc_version, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

qInitResources()
```

Ну и само фото, хотя оно вряд ли нужно здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создаем файл **kik.qrc**:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix='/'>
  <file>1/1.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

2. В консоле запускаем:

   `pyrcc5 kik.qrc -o kik_rc.py`

---

3. Запускаем приложение **main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(534, 498)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 220, 231, 31))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 260, 61, 31))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.AnswerEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 270, 141, 20))
        self.AnswerEdit.setObjectName("AnswerEdit")
        self.SetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 310, 101, 31))
        self.SetButton.setObjectName("SetButton")
        self.CheckButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 310, 111, 31))
        self.CheckButton.setObjectName("CheckButton")
        self.AnswerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 270, 101, 21))
        self.AnswerLabel.setText("")
        self.AnswerLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.AnswerLabel.setObjectName("AnswerLabel")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 380, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 380, 131, 51))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 261, 161))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/1/1.png);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/1/1.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 534, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "What do you see on this photo?"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type here:"))
        self.SetButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Answer"))
        self.CheckButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Answer"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to previous test"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to contests"))
import kik_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам вновь)

Comment: @Mswork6 пожалуйста

Comment: По какой то причине выполнение скрипта через кнопку, заставляло часть картинок в программе пропадать. Причём каждый раз рандомные изображения. С файлом ресурсов пока такой проблемы не обнаружил.