# Не отображаются изображения в QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qrc

Обращаюсь сюда с той же проблемой, что пару месяцев назад. Вновь не отображаются изображения в `QLabel`.

Делал всё по инструкции, которую мне написали, но все равно выходит ошибка:

> Could not create pixmap from :\page1\4a1.jpeg
>
> Could not create pixmap from :\page1\4a1.jpeg
>
> Could not create pixmap from :\page1\4a1.jpeg

Причем эта проблема началась недавно, пару недель назад. До этого все работало нормально. Прилагаю основной код **`Idioms.py`** и **`.qrc`** код.

**Idioms.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 0, 1081, 51))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 621, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 410, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 140, 301, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 260, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 360, 301, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 1081, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 140, 411, 341))
        self.label_12.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/page1/4a1.jpeg);")
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/4a1.jpeg"))
        self.label_12.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1100, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Unit 4a"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Come rain or shine!"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Idioms1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Under the weather</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - slightly unwell</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Yumi is feeling under the weather, so she won\'t be going to work today.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">On cloud nine</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - extremely happy</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Mo is on cloud nine - his wife is pregnant</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">A breeze</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - very easy</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Studying English is a breeze. I\'m progressin so quickly</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Rain cats and dogs</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - rain very hard </span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: I was going to go shopping, but it suddenly started raining cats and dogs, so I stayed home</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Save up for a rainy day</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - put some money aside for whenever it may be needed</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Once you have the basic home comforts, it\'s importnat to save up for a rainy day</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Storm in a teacup</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - small problem that has been blown out of proportion</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: In my opininon, the whole thing is just a storm in a teacup </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Head in the clouds</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - not being realistic or daydreaming</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: He can\'t continue going around with his head in the clouds; he must be more realistic about his problems</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to previous page"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to unit contents"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to next page"))
import Ids_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Ids.qrc**:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="page1">
    <file>4a1.jpeg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1141736/398802

Comment: Как я уже сказал, что я уже обращался с такой проблемой и делаю все точно так же как было описано в той статье что упомянул dIm0n, однако все равно выходит ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

обратите внимание на вторую и третью строку

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>page1/splash_.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
pyrcc5 Ids.qrc -o Ids_rc.py
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 0, 1081, 51))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 621, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 410, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 140, 301, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 260, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 360, 301, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 1081, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 140, 411, 341))
#???        self.label_12.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/page1/splash_.jpg);") # 4a1.jpeg)
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/splash_.jpg"))                  # 4a1.jpeg)
        self.label_12.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1100, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Unit 4a"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Come rain or shine!"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Idioms1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Under the weather</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - slightly unwell</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Yumi is feeling under the weather, so she won\'t be going to work today.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">On cloud nine</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - extremely happy</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Mo is on cloud nine - his wife is pregnant</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">A breeze</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - very easy</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Studying English is a breeze. I\'m progressin so quickly</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Rain cats and dogs</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - rain very hard </span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: I was going to go shopping, but it suddenly started raining cats and dogs, so I stayed home</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Save up for a rainy day</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - put some money aside for whenever it may be needed</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Once you have the basic home comforts, it\'s importnat to save up for a rainy day</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Storm in a teacup</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - small problem that has been blown out of proportion</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: In my opininon, the whole thing is just a storm in a teacup </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Head in the clouds</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - not being realistic or daydreaming</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: He can\'t continue going around with his head in the clouds; he must be more realistic about his problems</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to previous page"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to unit contents"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to next page"))
import Ids_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Нет. В `Ids.qrc` у меня есть приставка `page1`, в которой лежит `4a1.jpeg`. Само фото лежит в одной папке с `main.py` и `Ids.qrc`

Так тоже все работает:

**Ids.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="page1">
    <file>im.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

```
pyrcc5 Ids.qrc -o Ids_rc.py
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 0, 1081, 51))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 621, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 410, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 140, 301, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 260, 301, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 360, 301, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 1081, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 140, 411, 341))
#???        self.label_12.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/page1/splash_.jpg);") # 4a1.jpeg)
        self.label_12.setText("")
#       self.label_12.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/4a1.jpeg"))
        self.label_12.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/im.png"))            # 4a1.jpeg)   <----<

        
        self.label_12.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1100, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Unit 4a"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Come rain or shine!"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Idioms1"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Under the weather</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - slightly unwell</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Yumi is feeling under the weather, so she won\'t be going to work today.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">On cloud nine</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - extremely happy</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Mo is on cloud nine - his wife is pregnant</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">A breeze</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - very easy</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Studying English is a breeze. I\'m progressin so quickly</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Rain cats and dogs</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - rain very hard </span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: I was going to go shopping, but it suddenly started raining cats and dogs, so I stayed home</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Save up for a rainy day</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - put some money aside for whenever it may be needed</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: Once you have the basic home comforts, it\'s importnat to save up for a rainy day</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Storm in a teacup</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - small problem that has been blown out of proportion</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: In my opininon, the whole thing is just a storm in a teacup </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" text-decoration: underline; color:#55007f;\">Head in the clouds</span><span style=\" text-decoration: underline;\"> - not being realistic or daydreaming</span></p><p><span style=\" font-style:italic;\">Example: He can\'t continue going around with his head in the clouds; he must be more realistic about his problems</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to previous page"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to unit contents"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to next page"))
import Ids_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ниже показан очень простой файл ресурсов, содержащий один ресурс (значок нашего приложения).

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="icons">
        <file alias="hand_icon.ico">hand_icon.ico</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Имя между тегами `<file> </file>` - это путь к файлу относительно файла ресурсов.
`alias` - это имя, под которым этот ресурс будет известен из вашего приложения.
Вы можете использовать эти значки переименования для чего-то более логичного
или более простого в вашем приложении, сохраняя оригинальное имя внешне.

Например, если мы хотим использовать имя `application_icon.ico` для себя,
мы можем изменить эту строку на.

```
<file alias="application_icon.ico">hand_icon.ico</file>
```

Это только меняет имя, используемое ***внутри*** вашего приложения, имя файла остается неизменным.

За пределами этого тега находится тег `qresource`, который указывает `prefix`.
Это пространство имен, которое можно использовать для группировки ресурсов.
По сути, это виртуальная папка, в которой можно найти все вложенные ресурсы.

---

**Update 2**

> Проблему решил. Qt designer может обработать только png файл. Не знал об этом)

Это не так, кто вам об этом сказал? Вы бы лучше прикрепили свое изображение `4a1.jpeg`, чтобы увидеть что с ним не так.

**Ids.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="page1">
    <file>lena.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.py**

```
...

self.label_12.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/lena.jpg")) 

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: после замены кода в файле qrc у меня не получается переконвертировать файл в py. Выдаёт ошибку:

Cannot find file: page1/4a1.jpeg
No resources in resource description.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Mswork6  рядом с `main.py` и `Ids.qrc` у вас есть папка `page1`,  в которой у вас изображение `4a1.jpeg` - у вас так?

Comment: Нет. В Ids.qrc у меня есть приставка page1 в которой лежит 4a1.jpeg Само фото лежит в одной папке с main.py и Ids.qrc

Comment: @Mswork6 я добавил пример как вы описали - все работает.

Comment: Ошибка в консоли исчезла, однако картинка до сих пор не появляется. На месте label пустое место.

Comment: Upd: ошибка "Could not create pixmap from :\page1\4a1.jpeg" возникала только в том случае, когда я пытался так же поставить background-image для label с помощью styleSheet. Если же этого не делать, то ошибки нет, но картинка всё равно не появляется

Comment: Upd2: Я создал новый ui файл куда поместил один label в него вместил фото, и о чудо оно заработало, однако на том файле как ничего не работало, так и не работает. Честно говоря, не знаю что и думать на этот счёт.

Comment: Upd 3: Проблему решил. Qt designer может обработать только png файл. Не знал об этом)

Comment: @Mswork6   Это не так, кто вам об этом сказал? Смотрите мое новое обновление.