# Добавление файлов ресурсов в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, resources

Помогите, пожалуйста. Добавил файл .qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/48/images/flag.png</file>
        <file>C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/48/images/cubs.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Отметил его как файл ресурсов. При вводе в терминале выдает такое:

```sh
PS 
C:\Users\Roman\PycharmProjects\48\resources> pyrcc5 -o icon_rc.py icon.qrc

Cannot find file: C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/48/images/flag.png
Cannot find file: C:/Users/Roman/PycharmProjects/48/images/cubs.png
No resources in resource description.
```

Как же добавить эти злополучные ресурсы(( уже несколько дней мучаюсь... GPT chat говорит мол проверь есть ли там файлы, убедись что ты не олень))

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161322/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-qlabel/1161338#1161338 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141736/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5-pyqt5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83 если не получится, напишите.

Comment: Мне нужно было добавить png файлы для ярлыков треев в верхнем левом углу, так чтобы они были в ехе файле и использовались им. Получилось сделать это другим способом. Добавил функцию с sys._MEIPASS и  через auto-py-to-exe добавил файлы. Спасибо вам за ответ все-равно когда-нибудь придется разобраться с этими ресурсами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить файлы через `auto-py-to-exe` без файла ресурсов. 
В моем примере сохранил **.png** файл в корень папки там же где и **main.py**, прописал функцию `def resource_path(relative_path)` и использование файла как ярлыка окна

```
icon = QIcon(resource_path("flag.png"))
MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

потом при запуске `auto-py-to-exe` добавляем файл (там это сделать легко по кнопкам)

---

```
import sys 
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(990, 520)
    
        icon = QIcon(resource_path("flag.png"))
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
```